# How to print running total on last page of report using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, count

This is code splitting every 19 row on one page I need to get count of all rows on last page only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<DATA_DS>
<xsl:variable name="var_size" select="19" />
<xsl:for-each select="/DATA_DS/G_1">
<xsl:variable name="var_pos" select="position()" />
<xsl:variable name="var_mod" select="$var_pos mod($var_size)" />
<xsl:if test="$var_mod = 1">
<xsl:variable name="var_groupNum" select="($var_pos - $var_mod) div number($var_size) + 1" />
<xsl:element name="CountGroup">
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Group',$var_groupNum)" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:for-each select="/DATA_DS/G_1[position() &gt; ($var_pos -1) and position() &lt; ($var_pos + $var_size)]">
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</DATA_DS>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I Try `<xsl:if test="position()=last()">`

but still not work`your text`

Comment: Are you really using XSLT 2? It has a `for-each-group select="Row" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 19"` and then `if (position() eq last())` will tell you whether you process the last group/page.

Answer (score 0):

Example of the suggestion from the comment to use `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 19">
        <page count="{position()}" is-last-page="{position() eq last()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </page>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Example fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22root%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22item%22%20group-adjacent%3D%22%28position%28%29%20-%201%29%20idiv%2019%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpage%20count%3D%22%7Bposition%28%29%7D%22%20is-last-page%3D%22%7Bposition%28%29%20eq%20last%28%29%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fpage%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%201%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%202%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%203%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%204%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%205%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%206%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%207%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%208%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%209%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2010%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2011%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2012%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2013%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2014%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2015%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2016%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2017%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2018%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2019%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2020%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2021%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2022%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2023%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2024%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2025%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2026%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2027%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2028%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2029%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2030%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2031%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2032%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2033%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2034%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2035%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2036%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2037%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2038%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2039%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2040%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2041%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2042%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2043%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2044%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2045%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2046%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2047%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2048%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2049%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2050%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2051%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2052%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2053%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2054%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2055%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2056%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2057%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2058%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2059%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2060%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2061%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2062%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2063%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2064%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2065%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2066%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2067%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2068%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2069%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2070%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2071%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2072%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2073%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2074%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2075%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2076%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2077%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2078%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2079%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2080%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2081%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2082%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2083%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2084%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2085%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2086%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2087%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2088%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2089%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2090%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2091%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2092%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2093%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2094%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Citem%3Eitem%2095%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML).

For an XSLT 2 processor the grouping is the same, replace the declarative `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template